# How to use webpack to ignore a module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, next.js, monorepo

I have shared code that is used in the backend and frontend (I use Next for the frontend).

A piece of the shared code (library):

```js
import { ApiProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger'

export class AccessTokenResponseDto {
    @ApiProperty({
        example: 'xxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx',
    })
    public token!: string
}
```

Now I want to ignore `@nestjs/swagger` in the frontend BUT do not lose the functionality of the documentation feature in the backend.

The reason why I want to ignore `nestjs` in the frontend is to reduce the build size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:   https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#root

The externals configuration can exclude dependencies.

And you need two different script in package.json to distinguish different building env（one for frontend, one for backend）.